# Monic polynomial of minimal degree

Tags: polynomials, integral-domain

> $R$ is an integral domain. Let $x\neq0$ and $f\in{R[t]}$ of minimal degree such that $f(x)=x^n+r_1x^{n-1}+\dots+r_n=0$. Then $r_n\neq0$.

Why is this true? I know that integral domain means if we have $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

We assumed $x\neq0$ so if we assume $r_n=0$, we have
$$
f(x)=x^n+r_1x^{n-1}+\dots+xr_{n-1}=0
$$
and we can write
$$
x(x^{n-1}+r_1x^{n-2}+\dots+r_{n-1})=0
$$
so we know
$$
x^{n-1}+r_1x^{n-2}+\dots+r_{n-1}=0
$$
but I can't see why that would lead to a contradiction. Help please.

Comment: Was there an assumption that $n$ was the minimal degree?

Comment: @SamFreedman  yes! I forgot to write it. I understand now, if $a_n=0$ then $x^{n−1}+r_1x^{n−2}+...+r_{n−1}=0$ will be a contradiction to $f$ being minimal! Thanks!!

Comment: I think you’re basically done then, as you’ve contradicted the minimality of $n$ with your new resulting polynomial.

Comment: HINT.-You can work in $\mathbb Z$ in order to see easier. If $r_n=0$ then you have $x(x^{n-1}+r_1x^{n-2}+\ldots+r_{n-1})=0$ and because $x\ne 0$ you must have $x^{n-1}+r_1x^{n-2}+\ldots+r_{n-1}=0$. It follows that $x$ is root of a polynomial of degree least that $n$, which is absurde. (You must use the fact that $R[t]$ is also an integral domain.)

Answer (score 1):

This leads to a contradiction since you found a monic polynomial $g(t)=t^{n-1}+r_1t^{n-2}+\dots+r_{n-1}$ of degree $n-1<n=\deg f$ such that $g(x)=0$.